# How to make my view controller scrollable?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to make a screen that scrolls. I am using the ViewController to insert multiple UIViews with the background white, and the ViewController background color is gray. In the UIviews I have multiple buttons and I would like to add more down. But I am not being able to do that because I need to scroll down. I am very recent in Xamarin iOS and in the app delegate I am doing this:

```
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            ViewController v = new ViewController();
            Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
            Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
            Window.RootViewController.View = v.View;
            return true;
        }
```

Is this (UIScree.MainScreen.Bounds) disabling the scroll? How can I solve this problem? I tried to use UIScrollView but what I have already done disappears, it isn't supposed to, right? Or do I have to do all of this all over again? 
I am doing this all in code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think you need is a UIScrollView in your ViewController, Have you tried something like :

```
var scrollView = new UIScrollView (
new CGRect (0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height));
View.AddSubview (scrollView);
```

And then add all your Views into the ScrollView instead of the Main View!

Edit:

Your Finished launching would look something like:

```
ViewController v = new ViewController();
        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
        Window.RootViewController= v
        return true;
```

And in your ViewController, you add the View as below:

```
var scrollView = new UIScrollView (
new CGRect (0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height));
View.AddSubview (subView); // Where SubView is the UIView that has your ui design
```

Comment: I did that and nothing disappeared! But it isn't scrolling?

Comment: Done you can check it out now

Comment: You need to create UIScrollView inside the ViewController, put all the views on scrollview , calculate  content size ,  creating ScrollView  in FinishedLaunching method is not a good idea..

Comment: What's the best way? Im a total newbie in this. I wil need this view to connect with other views after, doing it like this It will be a problem right?

Comment: The best way is to add The ScrollView in the ViewController while initializing that View check my answer again

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

// create our scroll view
scrollView = new UIScrollView ( new CGRect (0, 0, View.Frame.Width, View.Frame.Height));            View.AddSubview (scrollView);
// create our image view
imageView = new UIImageView (UIImage.FromFile ("Germany.jpg"));         scrollView.ContentSize = imageView.Image.Size;          scrollView.AddSubview (imageView);